# Android google map getting forcefully closed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, classnotfoundexception

I want to open google map in my app to show some location and have followed  all the steps given in [Google's API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_vs_api) and have also imported the project from \extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib. and have added it as library to my current project.
But when i run it in my emulator i am getting the following:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(986): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.google_map/com.example.google_map.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.google_map.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.google_map-2.apk.
```

If i run it in my android device it is getting forcefully closed.
Pls do help me

Comment: if you have updated adt to rev 22 right click on your project. goto properties. java build path. order export tab. Make sure Android private libraries is checked for both your project and library project. Clean and build. Try this